# How to call MSBuild.ExtensionPack through MSBuild arguments?

Tags: msbuild, windows-services, msbuildextensionpack

Hi i am using MSBuild Extension Pack to install windows service to the remote machine. I was testing this through command prompt and it successfully installed the service. I now want to call this extension pack using MSBuild arguments.

My code looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>
   <RemoteMachine>DevRemote</RemoteMachine>
   <RemoteUser>RemoteDomain\RemoteUser</RemoteUser>
   <RemoteUserPassword>RemotePassword</RemoteUserPassword>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>

<Target Name="Default">
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService TaskAction="Install" ServiceName="Backup Management" ServicePath="c:\WINDOWS\system32\taskmgr.exe" RemoteUser="$(RemoteUser)" RemoteUserPassword="$(RemoteUserPassword)" MachineName="$(RemoteMachine)" />
</Target>
```

How am i able to achieve this? From my guess the build arguments looks something like this:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployWinService=true;TargetWinServiceHost=DevRemote
```

But i am not sure about the arguments. Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually have two files, one with properties, another with targets. I also try to store all the needed properties in a file, so there is no need to pass anything from command line.

If you call the file with targets `main.msbuild` you can call it like that

```
msbuild main.msbuild /t:Default
```

where `/t` switch corresponds to the target name, and this is how you can specify which target to execute, so no parameters with `/p` needed.

From [examples](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/258a18b7-2cf7-330b-e6fe-8bc45db381b9.htm), this is how the default target may look like

```
<Target Name="Default">
    <!-- Install a service on a Remote Machine -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService 
        TaskAction="Install" 
        ServiceName="__TestService1" 
        User="$(User)" 
        Password="$(password)" 
        ServicePath="c:\WINDOWS\system32\taskmgr.exe" 
        RemoteUser="$(RemoteUser)" 
        RemoteUserPassword="$(RemoteUserPassword)" 
        MachineName="$(RemoteMachine)" />
</Target>
```